# Why does setState works after Navigator.push?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder why does setState works after Navigator.push? Actually, I met such examples, but how does it work, should not the `Navigator.pushNamed` redirect right when it called?

```
if (user != null) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/chat");
}
// will the setState be executed?
setState(() {
    showSpinner = false;
});
```

Comment: maybe you are calling it in async function use `if(mounted){ setState((){}) }`

Comment: it is onPress function and it's assync but the author does not use `if(mounted){ setState((){}) }`

Comment: if it is async function when it can be finished when state object is not in a tree, or in other words when you close the page

Comment: Yes it will but only when user returns back to this screen. That is if we want data from the screen we can have a async callback and after that we can refresh the page.